# Can coaxial TV aerial cables be flat/ribbon? To go under thick rug for TV opposite aerial socket

Tags: tv, ribbon-cable, coaxial

A round shaped one would cause a ridge in the carpet.

I already have setup a flat ethernet cable under the rug for similar scenario whereby device is opposite ethernet socket.

**Update** it's to carry DVB-T signals from an aerial in the roof.

Comment: Yes, just search for “ flat coaxial cable”. Technically some of it isn’t coaxial, but has adapters to coax on each end.

Answer (score 2):

A cursory search resulted in lots of flat "coaxial" cables from various online vendors. The idea behind cable TV coax is twofold: a characteristic impedance is maintained along the length of the cable, and the shield protects it from undesirable noise and interference.

A flat "coax" cable, properly designed, will maintain characteristic impedance by keeping the signal conductor a specific distance away from the reference conductor/shield. However the products I saw did not appear to have shielding around the whole cable. For a short run under a rug or carpet, I think they may work just fine. But you wouldn't want to run such a cable a long distance.

[image: Flat coax cable example]

Most of these examples appear to be intended for running through a window without drilling holes, and as such are generally fairly short (~20 cm or so).

Comment: +1 but maybe this will work: https://www.amazon.co.uk/MANAX-F-connector-shielded-gold-plated-grommets-White/dp/B00YBWECMA/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=flat+coaxial+cable&qid=1651269697&sr=8-4  Then I can use an adapter to convert to coaxial both ends.

Comment: JYelton - Hi, Since [this](/help/referencing) site rule requires answers to include a link to the source web page for copied resources used in that answer, I searched & found that image [here](https://www.canadasatellite.ca/Digiwave-Ultra-Flat-Ribbon-Coaxial-Cable-DGA66951-p/Digiwave-Ultra-Flat-DGA66951.htm) (as well as some other places) to help you. Do you want me to add that as the source link for you, or can you find the original source page that you used & add that link instead? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again @JYelton - the length of ribbon for my case needs to be about 4 or 5 metres, rather than the 20cm shown.

Comment: @SamGibson I didn't include a link because there were multiple sources and I didn't want to link to a specific product. If you'd like to include a link to the image source, that's fine; I probably should have credited the source instead of just copying and cropping a random result from image search.

Comment: @SamGibson I do recall that my source was a UK distributor rather than Canadian, but I don't think I could find it specifically again.

Answer (score 2):

If it’s a TV aerial, you can go old-school and use twinlead 300 ohm cable (which is flat) and use a balun at the TV input.

The antenna itself is 300 ohm usually, but if it isn’t use a balun to convert it from coax to twinlead at the point where it goes under your carpet.

Cable TV, not so much. Needs to be 75 ohm coax.

Comment: +1 thank you. Good to know in theory it will work as flat.